# ContextConfiguration stuck running tests

Tags: spring, maven, testing, junit, applicationcontext

Output

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.aus.alerts.CriticalAlertMngTest
[06/25/14 10:21:33:395](main) WARN  - pertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Could not load properties from class path resource [env/psplatform-${psplatform.bonus}.properties]: class path resource [env/psplatform-${psplatform.bonus}.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
HttpAdaptor version 3.0.2 started on port 9080
[06/25/14 10:21:44:799](main) INFO  - SyncConfiguration          - Current name instance queue: [localmachine-VirtualBox]
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 14.843 sec
Running xxxxxxxxxxxxx.aus.dispatcher.utils.collections.CalRangeBeanTest
```

So after this output test stuck data processing

Test Itself

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/com/xxx/yyy/spring/v1/testApplicationContext.xml"})
public class CalRangeBeanTest {

    @Test
    public void calendarDateBeanCollectionToListingDateRangeTest() {
        if(System.getProperty("integrationTest") != null && !System.getProperty("integrationTest").isEmpty() && System.getProperty("integrationTest").contains("false")) return;

        assertNull("null CalendarDateBeanCollection should be null", CalRangeBean.toListingDateRange(null));
        ...
    }

}
```

Previously I discovered that if some bean was not created correctly in context because some thing was missed test could not run too

How can I find the reason why test was stucked?

Comment: I found the reason by adding

<logger name="org.springframework">
   <level value="TRACE"/>
</logger>

into log4j.xml

Comment: If you wand to see all info about test running you could manipulate log4j.xml